# XCM: How to send assets from the local chain to another via democracy?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, xcmp

I am looking into XCMv2 and given the standard `XcmOriginToCallOrigin` configs on both chains:

[image: XcmOriginToCallOrigin]

and environment: [HydraDX runtime](https://github.com/galacticcouncil/HydraDX-node/tree/master/runtime/testing-hydradx) & [Acala runtime](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/tree/master/runtime/acala).

I was able to construct a `polkadotXcm.send` call to withdraw an asset from the sibling account on the other chain and send it back to a local account.

**But it does not seem to be possible to withdraw an asset from your local chain** (e.g. treasury or sibling) **and send them to a** (sibling) **account on the other chain via democracy** (dispatches as root).

Neither of the calls `send`, `execute` or `reserveTransferAssets` seems to provide the ability to do this and fails with `FailedToTransactAsset`. Presumably the xcm executor does not know from which account it should withdraw the asset and I could add a converter for `(origin: superuser, location:here)` and then use `execute` or `reserveTransferAssets`?

This is less favourable option tho as I would prefer not having to change anything in the runtime and use just an XCM call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to use `utility.dispatchAs` and then you can use `reserveTransferAssets`.